# Find next element, although the element has other parent (but common ancestor)?

Tags: jquery

How to get the next *day* after *.selected*?

```
$('day.selected').next('day')
```

works only for days inside the same week.

```
<calendar>
    <month>
        <week>
            <day/>
            <day class='selected'/>
        </week>

        <week>
            <day/>   //How to get this?
            <day/>
        </week>
    </month>

    <month>
    .
    .
</calendar>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general solution to find the next day element(irrespective of the parent element)

```
var idx = $('day.selected').index('day'),
    $next = $('day').eq(idx + 1);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GCrxk/), also [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GCrxk/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.selected').parent().next().find(':first-child')
```

Comment: What if the selected day isn't the last day in the week?

Comment: @JasonP Well, I just answer based on OP's situation. you can use Arun's answer though :P

Answer (score 1):

To handle all possible scenarios, something like this could be done:

```
var curDay = $('.selected');
var nextDay;

if ( curDay.next('day') ) {
    nextDay = curDay.next('day');
} else if ( curDay.closest('week').find('day') ) {
    nextDay = curDay.closest('week').find('day:first-child');
} else if ( curDay.closest('month').siblings('month').find('week day') ) {
    nextDay = curDay.closest('month').next('month')
        .find('week:first-child day:first-child')
}
```

Arun's answer is better, though.

Comment: What about if next day is on next month

Comment: Good call. That gets more complex.

Comment: @A.Wolff True, but that was not part of the question. :)

Comment: Also, what if the selected day isn't the last day in the week?

Comment: Updated with some logic for those scenarios.